# Crystal Reports Grouping ? (help)

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

I have a problem that I would love to get an answer to.  I have multiple orders, but I will show 1 for this example.  I have 6 line items but only 4 are tax, which is what I am interested in.  They are classified as having a `Break_type as 1`.

I would like to add the tax amounts together then divide that sum by the discount count of amt_break_seq when the amt_break_seq does not equal 1.  How can I set that up so I should get `14.71` as result.

Example.

```
break_seq
    1      122.63           
    1      122.63           
    2      2.45         
    2      2.45         
    3      12.26            
    3       12.26
```

Total Tax 29.42   = Break_seq has 2 distinct count so ultimately it should be `29.41 / 2`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't need the break_seq in report then directly use `break_seq <> 1`  in `Record selection Formula`.
2. If you need break_seq in report not in calculation then try below approach.

Create a formula `@Break Sequence` and write below code:

```
if break_seq <>1
then <<your value field here>>
```

Now for this formula create a running total to calculate.

Take field to summarize as the value and summarization option should be `sum`

Evaluate on change of `break_seq`.

Reset on change of `break_seq`